# anyone got an idea on how to set up an automatic walk cycle?

Tags: animation

Something that can be easily control by changing the object location. I wanted to set up for something simple, like in games, where the character walk but also can turn according to the direction. And also, be able to customize the walking animation to different styles, because, well, everyone walk differently. Anybody knows where to start? Theres a lot of tutorial for unity, but unfortunately, i found almost none to not helpful in blender. I did however found a few spiders like thingy walking animation, using curve. but i'm not sure if it'll apply the same for human. Anybody got an idea where to start? Oh, i tried NLA, its pretty confusing and pretty nightmarish to understand, I don't think it'll fit with my kind of animation. I can't add any keyframe in between the NLA action, or at least i'm not aware of how to, Example below

character closing the door
[image]
character look down on the ground
[image]
character look behind
[image]
character turn animation
[image]
character walk animation
[image]

if i add the NLA walking action, i can't customize the animation in between(close door, look down on ground etc). This 10 seconds took an hour to make, i waste most of it on the turning and walking animation.
So anybody got an idea, any solution would help.

Comment: i would download a walk animation from free mixamo side and tweak that. Walk animation "manually" is - in my opinion - really hard to do if it should look good. NLA might be a nightmare - but worth learning it. Try to find some tutorials on yt about it because it is very good and can solve a lot of tasks for you.

Comment: ...and what i wanted to add: i first learned the "low hanging fruits" like rigid body animations and such stuff. But all the things i left out because i didn't understand in the beginning like NLA turned out to be the most useful things once you understood them. Yes, NLA is for sure not intuitive, but a very powerful tool.